# Assignment of a return-values of method blocks in ruby

Tags: ruby

Taking the ruby API documentation explanation for [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_byte), it suggests that one receives a string when invoking this method together with a given block.

```
each_char {|cstr| block } → str
```

But when executing this in irb, the output is not as expected and only the string we started out with is returned.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> v = "foobar".each_char { |c| c + "." }
=> "foobar"
```

The problem this causes, is that assigning this method invocation is pretty deceiving, as it doesn't return the expected result, but merely the string we started with:

```rb
irb(main):002:0> puts v
foobar
=> nil
```

Using the `break` instruction is the only way to return a value from the block during the variable assignment.

```rb
irb(main):003:0> v = "foobar".each_char { |c| break c + "." }
=> "f."
```

> **Questions:**
>
> Why do methods invoked with a block not return the values they calculate? Is this just a special case with this implementation, as I'm sure [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each) does return a new Array. But then again, [String#each_byte](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_byte) isn't returning something neither. What is going on here?
>
> What is the most elegant way to assign the processed values from the block?  Is monkey patching an option?

Additional infos:
I'm using ruby 2.6.3

(Note: I've seen [this question from Ed] but while the conclusion in 2017 was that using the assignment operator leads to syntax errors, ruby clearly doesn't behave like this in the case of `Array#each`.)

Comment: Um, `Array#each` also returns `self`. Are you looking for the `map`/`collect` methods?

Comment: Although not related to the actual question, your example can be achieved with `'foobar'.gsub(/(?<=.)/m, '.') #=> "f.o.o.b.a.r."`.

Comment: I suggest you remove all the tags except for “Ruby”, because it’s not likely that anyone would filter on any of the other tags, as they would know that they would miss many answers of interest by doing so. Suppose, for example, someone wanted to look at Ruby answers that used `each`. There might be thousands with the tag “Ruby” that do so, but yours might be the only one that also has the tag “each”.

Comment: I'm not really looking for map/collect or gsub. I just noticed that you can't assign the mutations done in the block of Array#each_char to a variable like the documentation suggests. The examples given here aren't really meant to achieve anything in particular.

Comment: "Why do methods invoked with a block not return the values they calculate?" - Some methods call the block more than once, e.g. `each`. Which of the values are they supposed to return, then?

Comment: Intuitively I would say, they return the same Type with which `each` was postfixed, joined together to the receivers type, but with the values mutated according to the last statement in the block. 
I'm aware you could solve this with `map`. And I explained my confusion in the comments to Alex's answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [`#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-each) not return a new array.
Each means that it will process each element of an array, but in the end, it will return it's receiver.

To print something from the block you need to use `print` or `puts`.

There are a few ways to assign the result of each:

First: using [#with_object](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_object)

```
=> v = "foobar".each_char.with_object('') { |c, obj| obj << c + '.'  }
=> v
=> "f.o.o.b.a.r."
```

One more: using [`#chars`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/chars) and [`#join`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join)

```
=> v = "foobar".chars.join('.')
=> v
=> "f.o.o.b.a.r"
```

Comment: so when #each return it's receiver, what dot #each_char (#each_byte) return? and what is the idea behind this inconsistency of returns?

Comment: @D.Asyl: `each_char` and `each_byte` return their receiver. *All* `each`-like methods always return their receiver. But actually, since the very purpose of `each` is only its side-effects, the return value doesn't even matter.

Comment: I could have sworn, that i tested the working of `.each` the other day and it returned indeed the expected array. It doesn't though, so my bad. There is nothing wrong then after all. This is ideed the solution. Thanks all.